# NSString substring between predefined strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can I get a substring between predefined strings. For example:

```
NSString* sentence = @"Here is my sentence. I am looking for {start}this{end} word";
NSString* start = @"{start}";
NSString* end = @"{end}";
NSString* myWord = [do some stuff with:sentence and:start and:end];

NSLog(@"myWord - %@",myWord);

Log: myWord - this
```

Comment: Look into NSString's `rangeOfString` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you the output you want:

```
NSString* sentence = @"Here is my sentence. I am looking for {start}this{end} word";
NSString* start = @"{start}";
NSString* end = @"{end}";

NSRange startRange = [sentence rangeOfString:start];
NSRange endRange = [sentence rangeOfString:end];

if (startRange.location != NSNotFound && endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *myWord = [sentence substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location + startRange.length, endRange.location - startRange.location - startRange.length)];
    NSLog(@"myWord - %@", myWord);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"myWord not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rangeOfString:`to get the location of each of the markers. Then use `subStringWithRange:`to extract the string part you want.

```
NSRange startRange = [sentence rangeOfString:start];
NSRange endRange = [sentence end];
NSString myWord = [NSString subStringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location+startRange.length, endRange.location-startRange.location+startRange.length)];
```

All code typed in Safari and no error handling included!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange startRange = [sentence rangeOfString:start];
NSRange endRange = [sentence rangeOfString:end];

int startLocation = startRange.location + startRange.length;
int lenght = endRange.location - startLocation;

NSString* myWord = [sentence substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startLocation, lenght)];
```